# .htaccess file dropping parts when not using [R]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want URLs that are of the structure `/news/categories/CATEGORY` to redirect to `/news/categories/dynamic-categories.php?category=CATEGORY`

And I have this working for most situations using this .htaccess file rule:

```
RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)/?$ /news/categories/dynamic-categories.php?category=$1 [L]
```

However, in certain situations, the category names have spaces, and this falls apart. Stuff like `/news/categories/with%20space` gets rewritten to where I'm only seeing the category GET parameter having the value of `with`.

However, an odd thing to add to this, if I add the redirect flag (`[R]`) into it, the rule works (although with a redirect...) and the whole category (`with space`) gets passed.

What do I need to change here?

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^news/categories/([^/]+)/?$ news/categories/dynamic-categories.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @anubhava That didn't do it either. It's still coming through for me as the one word.

Answer (score 0):

This actually appears to be an artifact of some other things.

The PHP page we're redirecting to is embedded though a CMS, and it looks like the query strings are getting stripped off during on of those transfer stages it does. The rewrite rule was right all along.